# Converting JSON property to array

Tags: angularjs

I have this property of JSON.
   "accessibleFunction":[1,2,3,4,5,6,13]

I want these to be in array like ["1","2","3","4","5","6","13"]

How can i do this?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking

Comment: I guess Json object should be in `{ ... }`. Why you mentioned it like `[ .. ]`

Comment: its like this --> { "accessibleFunction":[1,2,3,4,5,6,13] } actually

Answer (score 0):

i would simply do (if you have IE >= 9):

```
var myArray = accessibleFunction.map(function(entry){
   return entry.toString();    
});
```

See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) if you need more info on map function.

Comment: what would be the output if you print myArray?

Comment: anyway its telling me  accessibleFunction.map is not a function

Comment: the output would be ["1","2","3","4","5","6","13"]. You need to access your JSON in order to call that function. Without more code i can't figure out how you treat that json-

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
// assuming your json data in "jsonObject"

$scope.myArray = [];

angular.forEach('jsonObject', function (data) {
   $scope.stringData = data.toString();
   $scope.myarray.push(stringData);
});
```

Comment: By doing like this it results in ["[", "1", ",", "2", ",", "3", ",", "4", ",", "5", ",", "6", ",", "1", "3", "]"]

Comment: then try like, first convert data to string and then push it in array

Comment: still same output ["[", "1", ",", "2", ",", "3", ",", "4", ",", "5", ",", "6", ",", "1", "3", "]"]

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it with javascript [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

As the documentation says it will return a new array with the results of applied operation on each element. But you have to return it.

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in this array.

```
var accessibleFunction = [1,2,3,4,5,6,13];

var accessibleFunctionConverted = accessibleFunction.map(function(val) {
  return val.toString();   
});

console.log(accessibleFunctionConverted); 

// result: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "13"]
```

Comment: it results in accessibleFunction.map is not a function